# How to write a method to accept a type as a parameter and use it within the method body to cast another variable into that passed type?

Tags: c#

What I want is to have a method that accepts a type as a parameter and cast a variable into that type within the method in C#

as an example I want to pass a UI element to this helper method and extract its DataContext's (which is bound dynamically at runtime) Description. I want to use this method in a more generalized manner so that I can pass in the DataContext's type also.

```
private String GetDescription(FrameworkElement element, Type type) {
    return (element.DataContext as type).Description;
    //or 
    //return ((type)element.DataContext).Description; 
}
```

both the ways it ends up with a compile time error.

I tried using generics as well but it was not successful as i might not understood properly.

It would be really great if someone could explain how to do this in a simple manner.

Comment: It would work better with generics - maybe you should post that code.

Comment: I did not implement it. as I could not understand how to use it. Current progress is almost the same as the code snippet in the question

Comment: What do you mean by "DataContext Description"? Is this the name of the `DataContext`? Or do all of your bound `DataContext`'s have a property called `Description`?

Comment: The DependencyObject class does not have the DataContext property. So `element.DataContext` gives a compile time error, even before you get to casting to a type.

Comment: @NielsFilter - It is that my bound    DataContext has a property called    Description

Comment: @MikhailMozolin I am extremely sorry about the mistake. I perform that operation after casting it to a     FrameworkElement. Therefore I just changed the parameter type to     FrameworkElement here to make it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `interface` and implement it for your classes:

```
public interface IDescribable
{
    string Description{get;}
}
```

Implement this object on your desired classes:

```
public class MyClass:IDescribable
{
   // other members

   public string Description{get; set;}
}
```

Then you could even write an extension method to extract the string:

```
public static string GetDescription(this FrameworkElement element)
{
    var contextData= element.DataContext as IDescribable;
    return contextData!=null
           ? contextData.Description
           :"";
}
```

Or if you don't want implement `interface` use reflection:

```
private string GetDescription(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var decProp= element.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty("Description");
    return decProp!=null
           ?decProp.GetValue(element.DataContext)
           :"";
}
```

Comment: @MikhailMozolin Thank you for `FrameworkElement`. But both other suggested methods could cause runtime error. Your suggested `GetDescription<T>` could accept any data type in the `DataContext` and compiler could not check with defined constraints. Therefore using generic is useless.

Comment: In `String  GetDescription<T>(System.Windows.FrameworkElement element) where T : IDescribable` method  `where T : IDescribable` is a type constraint. So `GetDescription<T>` will only accept types that implement IDescribable, and this is checked at compile time.

Comment: @MikhailMozolin no it is not true. `DataContext` is a child member of FrameworkElement and its data type is `object` how compiler could check? [see fiddle as a example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvBLmM)

Comment: I solved the problem using reflection as for the last answer of @SamFarajpourGhamari It works fine for me. But I am wondering why there aren't any straight forward solutions for this as in my sample code snippet in the question.